# How to get name of all the files present in a change set using TFS Command line

Tags: .net, command-line, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to write batch script to move website project files by exporting from TFS & adding to application server. Requirement is to export / import all the files present in a change set.

I want to get all the file names present in a change set using command line. File name can then be used to execute tf get on those specific file.

I have tried, tf hostory & tf changeset commands

But at max, tf changeset command gives the following output -:

> ```
> Changeset: 151 User: Ashish Chandra Gupta Date: 11 October 2016 11:38:54
> ```
>
> Comment:   Change 6(ashish)
>
> Items:   edit $/SMT/SMT/CNSMT002.aspx.vb

I need the specific file name - CNSMT002.aspx.vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do the same in powershell, but I would suggest that you used the [REST TFS Api](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets) and [JsonConvert](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) like this:

```
        var collectionUrl = "http://YOURSERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/";
        var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };

        var changesetId = 181972;

        string json = client.DownloadString($"{collectionUrl}_apis/tfvc/changesets/{changesetId}/changes?api-version=1.0");
        XDocument document = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "changeset");
        var files = document.Descendants("path");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.Value);
        }
```

You might need to handle things differently depending if the files is added, changed or deleted.

JsonConvert can be obtained by installing the NuGet package *Newtonsoft.Json*. You can build specialized deserializers if you want to do more fine-grained things but above is the quick and dirty way of fetching the file names.

Comment: Can TFS REST APIs also be used to GET specific changesets, create workspace etc. which can be done using TFS Command Line.

Comment: @AshishChandra Yes, you can use the TFS REST APIs to get a specific file. As far as I can see you cannot create/edit workspaces.

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
SET tfs=http://YOUR_TFS_SERVER:8080/
:number
ECHO Enter changeset number (0 to exit):
SET /p chg=
IF NOT %chg% GTR 0 GOTO end
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" changeset /server:%tfs% %chg% /noprompt
GOTO number
:end
```

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/aqypwq/get-a-copy-pasteable-list-of-files-from-a-changeset-in-tfs

Comment: This seems to be what has already been tried in the question.